# equation of a circle that has a radius of $\sqrt{10}$

Tags: geometry

I am supposed to find the equation of a circle that has a center $(\sqrt{5},2\sqrt{2})$ and a radius $\sqrt{10}$.

I have no idea of solving an equation which the given center ($\sqrt{5},2\sqrt{2})$.

I know the distance formula but I don't know how to answer for the given center.

Comment: $(x-\sqrt{5})^2+(y-2\sqrt{2})^2=10$

Comment: use $(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you may know, the equation for a circle with center of $(x_c, y_c)$ and radius of $r$ is $$(x-x_c)^2+(y-y_c)^2=r^2.$$ So, the answer is $$(x-\sqrt{5})^2+(y-2\sqrt{2})^2=10$$